# The null space of $A$ is the plane $x+y=0$ and $T(1,0,0)=(1,1,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the standard matrix $A$?
So I started off like this:

$x+y=0$

$y=-x$

$\begin{pmatrix}x1 &-x1& z1\\x2& -x2& z2\\x3& -x3& z3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Any hints would be appreciated thank you!:)

Comment: The null space is a subspace so it cannot have the form $x+y=1$. $0$ is always in the null space for a linear operator.

Comment: Please check that I didn't change anything. I don't think I have but I can't find any way of seeing the original message since I proposed an edit for it so I can't check...

Comment: The title is incorrect.

Comment: Yes sorry it's x+y=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know $T e_3 = 0$, $T(e_1-e_2) = 0$ and $T e_1 = (1, 1, 0)^T$. It follows that $T e_2 = T e_1$.

You should be able to read off the matrix representation of $T$ in the basis $e_1,e_2, e_3$ from the above.

Hint:

> $T e_k$ gives the components of the $k$th column of the representation.